# difference between 'or' logic in c

Tags: c, gcc, logical-operators

In linux using gcc when I write a loop like this

`while(1 || 0)`

It enters the loop but when I write the loop like this

`while(0 || 1)`

it doesn't enter the loop. What is the differrence?

Comment: There is no difference and execution should enter the loop body. Can you share more of your code and/or compiler version used?

Comment: In both cases it should run infinite loop...

Comment: 2nd loop should enter on any standard C compiler. Show us the code how you are deciding that loop is not entered in 2nd case.

Comment: Did you forgot `break;` in first cycle? ;-) http://ideone.com/vWsBa

Comment: In both cases it run infinite loop...its perfectly working.

Comment: @pmg yet, result on your link is the same??

Comment: @pmg Oh, my bad! Thought your comment was somehow related to mine, since I created example on ideone too.

Comment: Ah! @Petr, my bad! :) I didn't even see the link on your comment (I think I just ignored all the final blue stuff as if all of it was a name, sorry). My comments deleted from here for cleanliness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you might be typing like

```
while(0||1);
```

Won't help you if you put ; after while loop

Answer (score 2):

There is no any difference. Execution should enter the loop in both expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference here. In this case. You're doing something else wrong.

---

But there's actually difference - in C/C++, there's [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) . So, as this is not your real code, this could help you.

For example, if you have

```
while( f() || g() )
// ..
```

if `f()` return `true`, `g()` will never be executed, as the expression will be evaluated to `true` immediately. The same for `&&`:

```
while( f() && g() )
// ..
```

if `f()` return `false`, `g()` will never be executed, because the value of the expression will be `false` for sure (independent of what `g()` will return here.

Well, if `f()` returns `true` (for the last example), `g()` *will* be executed, to calculate the value of the expression. The same with `||`, but then if `f()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases it run infinite loop...its perfectly working ...
there is no defference between them...

i think you are putting ; at the end of second while loop..
so remove that and see

Answer (score 0):

both code snippet have same behaviour. In both case condition will be true and will return infinite loop behaviour.